# Which activation functions should I use for polynomial regression?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, ai-design, activation-functions, regression

I am a beginner in machine learning and neural networks. I have only used neural networks for classification problems.  My aim is to modify it so that it can work for polynomial regression as well. In my problem, I have three inputs and three outputs. My aim is to predict these three outputs based on these three inputs. The outputs are real-valued, and can take positive and negative values.

How should I choose the activation functions? I have only used sigmoid.

Comment: For regression problems we use linear activation.

Comment: Try the popular ReLU activation function (or its variant, the leaky ReLU)

Comment: Thank you. I have one more doubt. The three input data are in the range of 100s eg(500,600,700) and the output have mixed units (700, -0.52, 0.45). Should I normalize the input as well as output ?